# Which serialization for sending protobuf via sockets in C++?

Tags: c++, sockets, serialization, protocol-buffers

Which kind of serialization is the most meaningful when sending serialized protobuf data via socket in C++? I use boost sockets.

Until now, I sent std::strings via sockets. I have the option to serialize the protobuf objects into a string and send this string via socket.

Is this slow or slower compared to the other serialization types offered by protobuf?

Comment: @Marc Gravell to send a string, the protobuf objects are serialized to a string which is send via socket.

Comment: I can't speak directly about the C++ version (as I'm C# focused), but my *expectation* is that sending direct to the stream-based approach should be more efficient. If nobody C++ familiar stops by, you might have to profile, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  All the serialization methods generate identical output using an identical algorithm.  The only savings you are going to have is in time memcpy-ing the data and perhaps the amount of memory used.  For all reasonably sized protocol buffers, this is negligible.

In general, you should pick the serialization method that makes your code most readable.

Comment: @Smokey-canoe I thought there is a performance difference between sending strings and sending bytes encoded streams. My messages won't get big enough, but I thought when the strings become hugs it's not expensive?!

Comment: SerializeToString() actually just returns a string object containing the identical bytes as ToArray or any of the other serialization methods.  The only difference is the datastructure the bytes are stored in.  (Try cout << proto.SerializeAsString() and you'll see - it's completely unreadable!  You can also try memcmping SerializeToArray vs. proto.SerializeAsString()... they're the same.)  If you want something textual that you can put in a browser cookie (for example), you'll need to Base64 encode it (or something else)

Comment: @platzhirsh, you're worried about making individual `write(2)` calls to the socket for each byte, which is slow. Using protobuf's `SerializeToString()` then writing out should be sufficiently fast. `SerializePartialToZeroCopyStream()` is going to be a better choice if you're worried about performance, though neither option is slow.